# 'transform' is not a member of 'object'

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm having a problem with shooter script. Unity in this section shows me the following error:

```
'transform' is not member of 'Object'
```

I tried to repair it, but it doesn't work. Any solution?

```
function ApplyDamage(dmg : float, hit)
{
    hit.transform.SendMessage("Damage",dmg);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `hit`?

Comment: Thats why JavaScript in unity3d is not my favourite. Maybe you habe to do something like  hit.gameObject.transform

Answer (score 1):

The most common error here is to assume that a generic `Object` is a `GameObject` one (that is, a subtype).

I would try one of these two approaches:

1) Defining `hit` as a `GameObject` directly in the parameter's definition:

```
 function ApplyDamage(dmg : float, hit : GameObject)
 {
    hit.transform.SendMessage("Damage", dmg);
 }
```

2) Accessing the  gameObject component of it:

```
 function ApplyDamage(dmg : float, hit)
 {
    hit.gameObject.transform.SendMessage("Damage", dmg);
 }
```